# queries and search keywords in couchdb documents

Tags: javascript, view, key, couchdb

I would search a keyword or search complex expression in a document stored in couchdb. There are examples that show me how can I proceed? An example, after storing a txt or pdf document, I need to search a particular word or expression inside the document

e.g the number of word "foo" in a pdf document stored in couchdb database, the expression "this is an example" inside a huge and long txt document.

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is called "full text indexing", if you search for that phrase, and add "couchdb" you will see all the different sorts of options like [Lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene/), [indexer](https://github.com/bdionne/indexer), and [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)